# Custom hook reset to its initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hook

```
export const useCreateAccount = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const onChangeInput: ChangeEventFunction = useCallback(({ target }) => {
    if (!target.files) {
      return setState({ ...state, [target.name]: target.value })
    }
    setState({ ...state, [target.name]: target.files[0] })
  }, [])


  return { onChangeInput }
}
```

Component

```
const { onChangeInput } = useCreateAccount()

<form>
 <input name="name1" onChange={onChangeInput}>
 <input name="name2" onChange={onChangeInput}>
</form>
```

Every time I do some change in second input(name2) the previous state(name1) of the component has been lost(reset to initial state), The reason I use 'useCallback', I only need one instance of 'onChangeInput'

But if I remove 'useCallback', state is keeping the previous values(name1)

I can't understand this behavior in hooks, can someone elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function):

> Any function inside a component, including event handlers and effects, “sees” the props and state from the render it was created in.

Here, when you are using `useCallback`, the function has been defined in it's initial render and has the initial state defined then. This is the reason why `useCallback` has a depedency array that can be used to refresh the function and values used inside it.

But you cannot use `state` as a dependency because you are setting the same inside it, instead you can use the [functional version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#how-do-i-update-state-with-values-that-depend-on-the-current-state) so as to get the previous values of state instead of reffering to the central one.

```
const onChangeInput: ChangeEventFunction = useCallback(({ target }) => {
    if (!target.files) {
      return setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [target.name]: target.value }));
    }
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [target.name]: target.files[0] }))
}, [])
```